# How to make, while clicking a button after the dropdown will come under automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
ul li:HOVER ul {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

The above is my code. But I want to while clicking in that list then automatically show that `ul`.

The following is my full code:

```
<ul>
     <li><img src="${context:layout/images/images.png}" id="list_image"/>
        <ul>
            <li><div id="list_name">First</div></li>
            <li><div id="list_name">Second</div></li>
            <li><div id="list_name">Third</div></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

2. Script:

   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(ul li).click(function(){
       $(this).find('ul').toggleClass('slow');
   })
   });

3.css:

```
ul 
{
display: inline;
list-style: none;
width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;height: 30px;float: left;
} 

ul li
{
display: inline-block; list-style: none; width: 100%; padding: 0px;
margin: 0px; 
height: 30px; float: left;
position: relative;
}
#list_image
{
height:20px; width:20px;margin-left: 35%; margin-right: 35%; margin-
bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px;
}
#list_name
{
height: 20px;padding-top: 5px;
}
ul li:hover {
background: #6B6B6B;
} 

ul li:ACTIVE ul {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
ul li ul {
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
right:0;
width: 125px;
box-shadow: none;
display: none;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
ul li ul li { 
background: #6B6B6B;
display: block; 
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background:#404040;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li').click(function(){
        $(this).find('ul').toggleClass('show');
    })
});
```

The above script will add a CSS class 'show' to the second level menu and remove the class on second click.

=======================================================================

I've checked your updated question

Found out that your following CSS is messing with the dropdown menu

```
ul li:ACTIVE ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
{
```

I've removed the CSS, and updated the CSS for the `ul li ul` as they contains too much hidden CSS,

Using the class toggle script now, and added css for showing the menu.
Please add transition yourself for more effect.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Math3w_C/xcuhy2L2/)** here.

Comment: Script ok. but in my css code, i want to make any change.

Comment: I've updated my answer, toggle a CSS class for flexible CSS controlling.

Comment: Once i have click that list the drop down will come and suddenly closed automatically. (its just like that LED blinking).

Comment: did you use 2 scripts together or? any preview link? or maybe a jsfiddle for preview? Please do note that ONLY use ONE script at a time.

Comment: I have updated my question. Is there have any mistake guide me.